# Django averages - average number of events per weekday

Tags: django

Given the following model:

```
DAY_OF_WEEK_CHOICES = (
    ('monday', 'Monday'),
    ('tuesday', 'Tuesday'),
    ('wednesday', 'Wednesday'),
    ('thursday', 'Thursday'),
    ('friday', 'Friday'),
    ('saturday', 'Saturday'),
)

class EventForDay(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, db_index=True)
    day_of_week = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=DAY_OF_WEEK_CHOICES,
        db_index=True)
    day = models.DateField(db_index=True)
```

Is there an easy way to query the average number of events that happen per weekday?

Comment: What do you mean by easy? What do you mean by weekday?

Comment: By easy I mean with the ORM, possibly using aggregates instead of raw SQL, and by weekday I mean day of week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django's [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) queries could help, perhaps something like (untested):

```
from django.db.models import Avg
WEEKDAYS = ('monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday')
EventForDay.objects.filter(day_of_week__in=WEEKDAYS).annotate(Avg('day_of_week'))
```